# Making only some HTML fields required depening on Radio button selection

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function ptCheck(that) {
    if (that.value == "N") {
        var x = document.getElementById("ps");   
   x.style.display = "none"; 
    x.required = false; 
    } else {       
    var y = document.getElementById("ps");   
   y.style.display = "block"; 
    y.required = true; 
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="pt" value="A" onchange="ptCheck(this);">
<span class="custom-control-label">A</span>
<input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="pt" value="N" onchange="ptCheck(this);">
<span class="custom-control-label">N</span>

<!-- the following will appear if "A" is selected in above radio button & the following needs to be mandatory -->
<input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="ps" required value="F" onchange="psCheck(this);">
<span class="custom-control-label">F</span>                        
<input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="ps" required value="M" onchange="psCheck(this);">
<span class="custom-control-label">M</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple, you just need to remove and add the required attributes through javascript

```js
const firstRadioGroup = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="pt"]');
const secondRadioGroup = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="ps"]');
const form = document.getElementById('form');

firstRadioGroup.forEach((radio) => radio.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    if(event.target.value == 'A') {
      // Remove the class from the parent div to show the radios and add require attribute
      document.getElementById('secondRadioGroup').classList.remove('hide');
      // Add required to the first radio, only need add to one if they have same name
      secondRadioGroup[0].required = true;
    }
    else {
    // Perform the opposite if is not the intended value
      document.getElementById('secondRadioGroup').classList.add('hide');
      secondRadioGroup[0].required = false;
    }
}))

// Handle form when submitted
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  alert('form submitted');
});
```

```css
.hide {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" method="post">
<input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" required name="pt" value="A">
<span class="custom-control-label">A</span>
<input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="pt" value="N">
<span class="custom-control-label">N</span>

<div id="secondRadioGroup" class="hide">
<input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="ps" value="F">
<span class="custom-control-label">F</span>                        
<input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="ps" value="M">
<span class="custom-control-label">M</span>
</div>

<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setAttribute` and `removeAttribute` to update the `required` attribute status.

```js
function ptCheck(that) {
    if (that.value == "N") {
        var x = document.getElementsByName("ps");
        x.forEach(item => {
            item.style.display = 'none';
            item.removeAttribute('required');
        });
    } else {
        var y = document.getElementsByName("ps");
        y.forEach(item => {
            item.style.display = 'inline-block';
            item.setAttribute('required', 'required');
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="pt" value="A" onchange="ptCheck(this);">
<span class="custom-control-label">A</span>
<input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="pt" value="N" onchange="ptCheck(this);">
<span class="custom-control-label">N</span>

<!-- the following will appear if "A" is selected in above radio button & the following needs to be mandatory -->
<input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="ps" required value="F" onchange="psCheck(this);">
<span class="custom-control-label">F</span>                        
<input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="ps" required value="M" onchange="psCheck(this);">
<span class="custom-control-label">M</span>
```